# Errors when trying to reverse a string

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtime-error, syntax-error

Get a input string, reverse it and parse it with '-':

input: `computer`

output: `r-e-t-u-p-m-o-c`

Why this code is giving errors and how to remove them?

```
package Set1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ClassSet15 {
    public static String reversedAndParsedString(String s1){
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s1);
      sb.reverse();
      StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer();
      for (int i = 0; i < (2 * s1.length()) - 1; i++)
        if (i % 2 != 0)
          sb1 = sb.insert(i, '-');
      return sb1.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("enter the String:");
      String s1 = s.next();
      System.out.println("the formatted string is:" + reversedAndParsedString(s1));
    }
}
```

This error is coming:

Main.java:3: error: class ClassSet15 is public, should be declared in a file named ClassSet15.java public class ClassSet15 { ^ 1 error

Comment: Could you please indent your code properly so we can read it? Your IDE can do it. It may also make it easier for yourself to spot what could be wrong.

Comment: Which errors are you getting? Please paste them into the question.

Comment: I don’t get any error from running your code. The output I get is `the formatted string is:r-e-t-u-p-m-o-c`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no actual error with the code. It runs as expected. The issue is that you don't have your `ClassSet15` in a file named `ClassSet15.java` as you must in the Java world. The error tells you exactly that:

> Main.java:3: error: class ClassSet15 is public, should be declared in
> a file named ClassSet15.java public class ClassSet15 { ^ 1 error

So please change your file name from `Main.java` to `ClassSet15.java` and everything will work as expected.